# Conditional format using exact text from another cell

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a column of names (L:L) to which I need a conditional format that highlights a specific name in the column.

The name is set by the value of another cell elsewhere (B3) in the sheet and changes frequently, hence the highlighted name in L:L will also change each time depending on what the value of B3.

I can't figure out how to reference the value of B3 in either Exact Text or Custom Formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use the format rule `Text is exactly` and have your desired cell locked via an absolute reference: `=$B$3`.

Absolute reference is required because otherwise the cell which the formatting rule evaluates against changes as the rule checks for different cells further down the column. For example, if the rule `=B3` was used on the range L:L, it would evaluate L1 against B3, L2 against B4, L3 against B5, and so on.

You can read more about formatting rules [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413).